# C++ program crashes. Graph implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, crash

I'm trying to implement a Graph data structure which uses an adjacency list. To populate, I have to read data from a file. The file is a text file where the first line contains two numbers. The first is the number of vertices n and the second is the number of edges m. After this line there will be m lines with three numbers. The first two numbers represent the source and destination vertex for the undirected edge. The third number (positive integer) is the weight for that edge.

The file's contents look like this:

```
5 7
0 1 3
0 2 4
0 3 5
1 4 10
2 5 20
3 4 6
4 5 4
```

But for some reason the code I've written so far makes the program crash. And compiler doesn't give any hints as to the reason.
I'd really appreciate some advice. I've read quite a lot about pointers, references in C++, but still finding them confusing. So a good resource to understand them better would really be helpful.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Vertex
{
    unsigned value;
    vector<Vertex*> adjList;
    vector<unsigned> weights;
};

class Graph
{
private:
    unsigned vertex_count, edge_count;
    vector<Vertex*> vertices;


public:
    Graph(string fileName)
    {
        ifstream myFile(fileName);

        if (myFile.is_open())
        {
            // Processing the first line of the file
            string aLine;
            getline(myFile, aLine);
            stringstream aString(aLine);

            aString >> vertex_count;
            aString >> edge_count;

            // Processing the rest of the file
            unsigned vert1, vert2, weight;
            while (getline(myFile, aLine))
            {
                aString= stringstream(aLine);
                aString >> vert1;
                aString >> vert2;
                aString >> weight; 
                addRelation(vert1, vert2, weight);
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "Unable to open file.";
    }

    ~Graph()
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
            delete vertices[i];
    }

    void addVertex(unsigned val)
    {
        Vertex* newVertex = new Vertex;
        newVertex->value = val;
        vertices.push_back(newVertex);
    }

    Vertex* findVertex(unsigned val)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
            if (vertices[i]->value = val)
                return vertices[i];
        return nullptr;
    }

    void addRelation(unsigned vert1, unsigned vert2, unsigned weight)
    {
        Vertex* vertex1 = findVertex(vert1);
        if (vertex1 == nullptr) {
            addVertex(vert1);
            vertex1 = findVertex(vert1);
        }

        Vertex* vertex2 = findVertex(vert2);
        if (vertex2 == nullptr) {
            addVertex(vert2);
            vertex2 = findVertex(vert2);
        }

        vertex1->adjList.push_back(vertex2);
        vertex1->weights.push_back(weight);

        vertex2->adjList.push_back(vertex1);
        vertex2->weights.push_back(weight);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Graph myG("graph.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, enable more warnings, it's always good to have extra warnings enabled when developing. Secondly, run in a debugger to locate the crash. The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine (and walk up) the function call stack and also let you examine values of variables at each level. Of course you need to build with debug-info for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if expression is assigning not comparing.

```
Vertex* findVertex(unsigned val)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        if (vertices[i]->value = val)  // WHOOPS!
            return vertices[i];
    return nullptr;
}
```

Change to:

```
Vertex* findVertex(unsigned val)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        if (vertices[i]->value == val)  // FIXED
            return vertices[i];
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I was using the command line and therefore missed that mistake. I thought I did something wrong with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Several of your if statements use = instead of ==. If you enable warnings in your compiler, you will find something like:

```
test.cpp:69:36: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
            if (vertices[i]->value = val)
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
test.cpp:69:36: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
            if (vertices[i]->value = val)
                                   ^
                (                       )
test.cpp:69:36: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
            if (vertices[i]->value = val)
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped. Such  a stupid mistake :). I expected I messed something up again with pointers.